# Concatenation of Lists in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Can someone help me find the error in these rules?

```
concat([], List, List).
concat([Head|[]], List, [Head|List]).
concat([Head|Tail], List, Concat) :- concat(Tail, List, C), concat(Head, C, Concat).
```

Trying to concatenate two lists fails:

```
| ?- concat([1,2], [4,7,0], What).

no
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To fix your code, the way you intended it, you just need to transform `Head` into `[Head]` in your last call to `concat/3` in your last clause. The problem was that you called your predicate with `Head` only as first argument, which is not a list.

Though, here are several notes :

- `[Head|[]]` is equivalent to `[Head]`
- your algorithm has a poor complexity, n! I believe.
- with no cut inserted after your second clause, you generate infinite choice points through the call of your third clause with a list of length 1 (that hence calls your second clause, that then is ran through your third clause, etc... infinite loop).

Here is SWI-pl's version, to hint you towards good prolog recursion :

```
append([], List, List).
append([Head|Tail], List, [Head|Rest]) :-
    append(Tail, List, Rest).
```

You can find other resources on recent posts here or in [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch3) tutorial if you want to learn how to use recursion properly.

Comment: Thanks for helping. One more question: is it possible to see how prolog interpretes the program? for example, stack trace could help to see the problem.

Comment: yup, type `trace.`. You'll enter trace mode. To leave it, type `notrace`. You'll be in debug mode. To leave debug mode, type `nodebug.` and you'll be back in normal mode !

Answer (score 8):

It can be done by using append.

```
concatenate(List1, List2, Result):-
   append(List1, List2, Result).
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the concatenation between two lists rule:

```
concat([],L2,L2). concat([Head|Tail],L2,[Head|L3]) :- concat(Tail,L2,L3).
```

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is very simple.
concatenation is nothing but appending the second list at the end of the first list.
Keep on adding until the first list runs out of elements. Now add the second list to it.

```
ap([],L,L).
ap([H|T],L,[H|Z]):- ap(T,L,Z).
```

**OUTPUT**

```
?-ap([1,2,3],[a,b,c],List).
  List=[1,2,3,a,b,c]

?-ap([1,2,3],[a,b],List).
  List=[1,2,3,a,b]

?-ap([1,2],[a,b,c],List).
  List([1,2,a,b,c])

?-ap([],[],List).
  List=[]
```